# Java Checkers - removing Icon, java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, icons

I have a problem with checkers, doing jump doesn't work, I have no idea what can I do to this would work, please help or give me some hints :)

```
public class DnD extends JFrame {

    private JPanel boardPane;
    Icon z = null;
    JLabel jlabel = new JLabel();
    String k="";
    String ballPressed="";
    String p="";

 public DnD(){
    super("Checker");

    icdim = new Dimension(greenIcon.getIconWidth() + 5, greenIcon.getIconHeight() + 5);
    boardPane = new JPanel();
    board = new JLabel[8][8];
    dragged = new JLabel();
    layers = getLayeredPane();
    mouseHandler = new MouseInputAdapter() {

 public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouseevent) {

            JLabel jlabel = (JLabel)mouseevent.getSource();
            Point point = jlabel.getLocation();
            Point point1 = mouseevent.getPoint();

            point.translate(point1.x, point1.y);
            Component component = boardPane.getComponentAt(point);
            JLabel jlabel1 = jlabel;

            if(hasIcon(component))
                    if(allowedMove(jlabel, component, k))
                            jlabel1 =(JLabel)component;
                    else
                        try{
                            if(bicie(jlabel,component,k))
                                jlabel1 =(JLabel)component;
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            jlabel1.setIcon(dragged.getIcon());
            dragged.setVisible(false);

        }
 };

   boolean jump(JLabel jlabel, Component component)  {
      int x = jlabel.getX();
      int y = jlabel.getY();
      int x2=  component.getX();
      int y2=  component.getY();
      String h="";

      if(ballPressed=="redIcon" && player==true && y-y2==138 && x2-x==138){
          Point point = new Point(x+69, y-69);
          JLabel l=  (JLabel) jlabel.getComponentAt(point);
          try{
          q=l.getIcon();
          h = q.toString();

            if(h=="greenIcon"){
                player = false;
                message.setText("Green");
                getComponentAt(x2+69, y2+69).setBounds(0,0,0,0);
                ((JLabel) q).setIcon(null);
              return true;

          }
      }else

    return false;
}
```

For jump I gave small part of code ( just for redIcon in right way) , because I want to be readable.

For line 
            `q=l.getIcon();` I get `java.lang.NullPointerException`

http://s2.postimg.org/ywdxs56qx/exception.jpg

Comment: what is this `ballPressed=="redIcon"` and `h=="greenIcon"`. Is it string equality comparison. Use `String#equals()` method.

Comment: ballPressed is String which show icon is dragged (red or green). But I think this won  help me with my problem. But you are right that a should use String.eguals(), thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If `q=l.getIcon()` gives null pointer, then l is almost certainly null.  You derive l from JLabel.getComponentAt(), with some calculations; getComponentAt returns null if "the component does not contain the position".

Comment: Does it mean that it never see component inside blue circle??

http://s27.postimg.org/f5pdlcdgz/jump.jpg

Comment: I don't know when jump() is called; I don't know what the values for JLabel and Component represent, much less what their actual values are for the call that is throwing the exception.  I don't know if this does this every time or only under some circumstances.  Put this in a debugger, stop it on q=l.getIcon(), and look at the vales for x+69 and y-69 and compare with the values on your game grid (which I also don't know), and see where in (or out of) the grid the code is attempting to get a component.